# Typeahead in Bootstrap:The suggestions keep there when the input doesn't matches

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js

I'm using typeahead in Bootstrap for my application using Ajax to get suggestions from the server side.
    Everything is fine except:I'm writing the correct input and getting suggestions like 'The Walking Dead'.When I start to input the wrong input,like the walkkkk,the suggestions are still there unless I press the key ESC.It annoys me.
[image]

    I've checked the server side,when I starts to input the wrong input,the server returns nothing.
    How can I hide the suggestions automatically?

Here is the relative js code:

```
$('#query').typeahead({
    source: function(query, process){
        suggestions = {};
        labels = [];
        $.post('suggest.do', {query: query, limit: '10'}, function(data){
            var sugg = jQuery.parseJSON(data).data;

            if(sugg == 'NOTHING' || sugg == 'ERROR'){
                return;
            }
            $.each(sugg, function(index, item){
                suggestions[item.name] = item;
                labels.push(item.name);
            });
            return process(labels);
        });
    },
    items: 10,
    minLength: 1,
    updater: function(item){
        //irrelative code
    },
    matcher: function(item){
        return true;
    },
    highlighter: function(item){
        var ent = suggestions[item];
        var html = '' +
                    '<div class="entity-block">' +
                    '<span class="label label-important">' + ent.type + '</span>&nbsp;' + 
                    '<span class="sugg-name">' + ent.name + '</span>' +
                    '</div>';
        return html;
    }
});
```

Comment: why dont you just clear the suggestion before sending a asynchronous request to server

Answer (score 0):

```
source: function(query, process){
    suggestions = {};
    labels = [];
    $.post('suggest.do', {query: query, limit: '10'}, function(data){

        //Check if any data is returned, if not clear the text and exit the func
        if(!data || data.length == 0){
           $('#query').val("");
           return;
        }

        var sugg = jQuery.parseJSON(data).data;

        if(sugg == 'NOTHING' || sugg == 'ERROR'){
            return;
        }
        $.each(sugg, function(index, item){
            suggestions[item.name] = item;
            labels.push(item.name);
        });
        return process(labels);
    });
},
```